# Adding CSS class to fields (Content Types)

Tags: theming

I added a new content type with some fields

I have a field to upload image, I want to add a CSS class to this specific field,
Should I done it via node-file.tpl.php

or via the dashboard and where?

Answer (score 0):

Try out [Field Formatter CSS Class](http://drupal.org/project/field_formatter_css_class) module.

> allows you to set any text/list/option/taxonomy field to render as CSS
>   class on the node. This enables the node author to select predefined
>   CSS styling per node.